# jquery parsing json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is the JSON output that I currently have:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "system.employees", 
"fields": {"chi_name": "N/A", "eng_name": "Eli"}}]
```

I want the output to be

```
[{"label": "Eli", "value": "1"}]
```

how can I take the values of pk and eng_name from the JSON data and output it like above?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
var data = [{"pk": 1, "model": "system.employees", 
    "fields": {"chi_name": "N/A", "eng_name": "Eli"}}];

var new = $.map(data, function(index, item) {
        return { label: item.fields.eng_name, value: item.pk };
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = [{"pk": 1, "model": "system.employees", "fields": {"chi_name": "N/A", "eng_name": "Eli"}}]
var output = [{ "label" : result[0].fields.eng_name, "value": result[0].pk}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//assuming your source obj is called 'source'
var num = source[0].pk;
var eng_name = source[0].fields.eng_name;
```

...then you can do whatever with them, like

```
var output = [];
output.push({"label":eng_name, "value":num});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
var h = JSON.parse('[{"pk": 1, "model": "system.employees", "fields": {"chi_name": "N/A", "eng_name": "Eli"}}]');
var a = [];
a.push({"label": h[0].fields.eng_name, "value": h[0].pk+''})
alert(JSON.stringify(a))
```

**NB** You'll need to import this code - https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js if your browser doesn't support `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify`

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/ipr101/uwZVW/